# Не работает опция shedule

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

С чем может быть связано нежелание `g++` компилировать `OpenMP` программу с использованной опцией `shedule(dynamic)`?

Флаг `-fopenmp` указан, опции задаются так, всё работает:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8), shared(foo, bar), default(none)
```

Если теперь добавить `shedule(dynamic)` или вообще любой `shedule`, то получаю

> error: expected ‘#pragma omp’ clause before ‘shedule’

Пробовал отдельно задать параллельный блок `#pragma omp parallel`, а в нём `#pragma omp for`, -- всё равно не хочет принимать.

Версии всего самые последние, непонятно почему другие опции работают, а эта нет.

Comment: потому что параметр прагмы называется `schedule`, а не `shedule`...

Answer (score 1):

Правильное название параметра `schedule`, с ним всё работает.